# Debugging Safari Error iPhone - Unable to Determine Cause

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari, remote-debugging

A particular web page causes Safari 9 to reload a few times, each time displaying a message "A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded" then finally just give up only showing "A problem repeatedly occurred on {page name}"

The error can only be duplicated on one of seven Apple devices that are available to us, an iPhone 7 Plus running Safari 9 using T-Mobile.  Emulators cannot reproduce the problem.

When using the Web Inspector and hooking the phone up to a Macbook to debug the issue and setting Safari to preserve the log upon navigation, the reload error causes the Web Inspector window on the Macbook to close, thus eliminating any error messages that may have been displayed.  Checking the Crash logs in the Macbook reveals no information about the crashed Web Inspector window.

I downloaded an app that lets me analyze RAM usage on the iPhone, and the phone has a good 1.5 Gigabytes of RAM left over, the page itself only contains about 25 high resolution images and html markup, seems to me hardly enough to consume the available RAM.  The confusing part is that it the issue is somewhat sporadic, I can open one tab and load the page fine, then the second tab opened will consistently error out as described above.

My main issue is that this software is not allowing me to determine what the error is.  The question at hand for devs with experience in Safari is, generally speaking, how would you go about determining the actual cause of an error in this very hostile development environment?

Comment: You should try to reduce the site to a minimum that still causes the problem and hang it somewhere people can access to help you out.

Comment: OK I will see if I can reproduce the error on a minimal test page, thanks for the advice

Comment: I could not duplicate the problem on a smaller page and it also turned out  that there were many different changes which could be made which all resolved the problem.  But the real question here wasn't "how to fix this specific issue", it was, generally speaking, what are reliable ways/ideas/strategies one could use in order to determine bugs in this very unfriendly dev environment.

Comment: @GantTheWanderer What did you change that eventually fixed the issue? I'm dealing with this myself on iPhone 7/Plus and can't seem to find anything that fixes the issue.

Comment: @AJB The page with the error was loading dozens of high resolution images into the DOM via img tags.  Particular photos were not resized/optimized for web, being far larger than appropriate.  After reducing the number of photos loaded, or removing them altogether, the crash stopped happening.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: If anyone else has this issue, I was able to narrow it down on Mac OS using the Develop tab. I disabled Styles / JavaScript / Images one by one until the page loaded to isolate the issue, which made it much easier to fix.